# Mysql query to check nodes created in last 3 month

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I want to query table node in which I want to check records created in last 3 Months. created is my field in table whose data type is timestamp
I tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM node
WHERE created >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') INTERVAL -3 MONTH
```

And also this

```
SELECT Count(*),DATE_ADD((DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), '%e %b %Y')),INTERVAL -3 MONTH) AS DATERANGE
FROM node
```

But both are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the simplest method I do date operations:

```
SELECT *
FROM node
WHERE created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH;
```

Comment: Not working
Error
Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "INTERVAL" at position 46)
Unexpected token. (near "3" at position 55)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "MONTH" at position 57)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM node WHERE created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'created' in 'where clause'

Comment: What tool are you using to get those messages? It works just fine on my Drupal 7 DB in the MySQL CLI

Comment: using wampserver in MySql